# How to implement async page refresh in django?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I have a page that displays last 10 requests to server. Requests are models that are saved by the middleware.
I need to update page with new requests, without refreshing.

I know I can use ajax, and ping server periodically, but sure should be better approach.

Comment: It depends of your needs. If you need best performance, you should use Websocket, if you don't need extra performance AJAX is a easier approach.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which is scheduled to be included in [django 1.10](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2016/3/17/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django)  (summer 2016)

It works via websockets instead of ajax polling

Comment: It would be great, I guess. But I am binded to django 1.6.

Comment: @user3684055 - Websockets or ajax polling are your only two options. You may want to consider upgrading django since [1.6 is no longer supported](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions)

Answer (score 1):

Async page refresh can be done only in front-end with `javascript`. Django will only render the template or return the HTTP response

P.S: You can do page refresh via backend code(Django) or any